# how to access a variable in another python file

Tags: python, firebase, kivy

I am trying to access the localId which is in my firebase.py in my main.py
here's a sample code from my firebase.py

```
    def sign_up(self, email, password):
        try:

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(sign_up_request.ok)
            print(sign_up_request.content.decode())



            if sign_up_request.ok == True:
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
```

how could I possible get access to the localId variable and reference it in another file, any help would be appreciated

Comment: `import firebase` then access it with `firebase.localId`?

Comment: As it stands, you cannot. The `localId` variable is local to the `sign_up` method and only exists while that method is executing (and only if `sign_up_request.ok` is `True`). You could change `localId =` to `self.localId =` to save it as an instance variable of whatever class that method is in. Then you could reference it as `instance.localId` where `instance` is an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: please can you explain it in detail, don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to access local variables in separate files. Try copying the code from one file and pasting it into the other one. The code is the file your showing in the question, and the "Lorem ipsum dolor..." will be the other one. (don't change the contents of the "other file" to the "Lorem ipsum...", it's just an example.) 
Try this:

> def sign_up(self, email, password):
>           try:

```
        app = App.get_running_app()
        email = email.replace("\n","")
        password = password.replace("\n","")

        # Send email and password to Firebase
        # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
        signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
        signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
        sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
        sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
        print(sign_up_request.ok)
        print(sign_up_request.content.decode())



        if sign_up_request.ok == True:
            refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

            localId = sign_up_data['localId']
            idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
    #file 2:
    #Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    #tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    #quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    #consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    #cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    #proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you posted must be in a class, but you didn't mention what that class is, so I will call it `SomeClass`. Then, we define `self.localId` in that class, in a file named `firebase.py`, so it looks like:

```
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize localId to None, just to be sure it always exists
        self.localId = None

    def sign_up(self, email, password):
        try:

            app = App.get_running_app()
            email = email.replace("\n","")
            password = password.replace("\n","")

            # Send email and password to Firebase
            # Firebase will return localId, authToken (idToken), refreshToken
            signup_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=" + self.wak
            signup_payload = {"email": email, "password": password, "returnSecureToken": True}
            sign_up_request = requests.post(signup_url, data=signup_payload)
            sign_up_data = json.loads(sign_up_request.content.decode())
            print(sign_up_request.ok)
            print(sign_up_request.content.decode())



            if sign_up_request.ok == True:
                refresh_token = sign_up_data['refreshToken']

                # set the value of localId
                self.localId = sign_up_data['localId']
                idToken = sign_up_data['idToken']
```

Then in your `main.py` you can access the `localId` as:

```
from firebase import SomeClass

someInstance = SomeClass()
someInstance.sign_up(email, password)
print('localId =', someInstance.localId)
```

Comment: the value returns as a Nonetype object when its meant to return as a string, can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: I don't think that the type of return is your problem. A `Nonetype` is `None`, literally nothing. That suggests that perhaps your `sign_up_data['localId']` is `None` or that your test `if sign_up_request.ok == True` is failing. Try adding additional `print` statements in your `sign_up()` method to see what is going on. For example, add a `print(sign_up_data)` just before setting `localID`.

Comment: everything seems to be working as planned except the localID keeps returning None, inspected all my code and still haven't found a solution, is there another thing  I can try?

Comment: Did you try adding print statements as I suggested? If so, what did they show?

Comment: it showed "True" and gave the necessary information

Comment: it print the id token, email, refresh token, all the necessary information. in that same python file, im using the local id to send information to the database and its working that is why im surprised that it is returning me Nonetype object in my other file